# When does $\operatorname{supp} (f \ast g) = \operatorname{supp}(f)+\operatorname {supp}(g)$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f,g \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ be two functions such that $ \operatorname{supp}(f)=S_1$ and $ \operatorname{supp}(g)=S_2$.

Let $\ast$ denote the convolution, I know that then $\operatorname{supp}(f \ast g) \subset S_1+S_2$.

Now I have read that allegedly if $f,g$ are non-negative then we get $\operatorname{supp}(f \ast g) = S_1+S_2$.

But I was not able to show/see why equality should hold.

Comment: What functions are you considering ? Continuous with compact support on some space ?

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc In general, I am looking at real functions with compact support. I am not sure if continuity is needed. After all, the convolution should make the functions continuous.

Comment: @John.W If $f(x)=g(x)=0$ for all $x\neq0$ and $f(0)=g(0)=1$ then $f$ and $g$ are nonnegative but $f\ast g=0$, so $\operatorname{supp}(f+g)\neq\operatorname{supp}(f)+\operatorname{supp}(g)$. If $f$ and $g$ are continuous and nonnegative then of course $f\ast g$ is continuous and nonnegative, and so $(f\ast g)(x+y)\geq f(x)g(y)>0$ for all $x\in\operatorname{supp}(f)$ and all $y\in\operatorname{supp}(g)$.

Comment: you will need some characterization of the essential support of a function $f\in L^1$ to prove that. There is one: $x\notin \operatorname{ess supp}(f)\Leftrightarrow \exists \delta >0: f|_{\mathbb{B}(x,\delta )}=0\text{ a.e. }$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition a point $a$ belongs to the essential support of a measurable function $f$ if for every $\delta >0$ we have $$|\{x\,:\, |x-a|\le \delta,\ |f(x)|>0\}|>0$$ The last condition is equivalent to the existence of $n$ such that
$$|\{x\,:\, |x-a|\le \delta,\ |f(x)|>n^{-1}\}|>0$$ Therefore an equivalent condition is
that for every $\delta >0$ we have $$\int\limits_{a-\delta}^{a+\delta} |f(x)|\,dx >0$$ Let $a\in {\rm ess\,sup} \,f$ and  $b\in {\rm ess\,sup} \,g.$ WLOG we may assume $b=-a.$ We want to show that  $0\in {\rm ess\,sup} \,(f*g).$  We have
$$\int\limits_{-\delta}^\delta (f*g)(x)\,dx =
\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(y)\,\int\limits_{-\delta}^\delta g(x-y)\,dx\ dy\\ =
\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(y)\,\int\limits_{|x+y|\le \delta} g(x)\,dx\ dy \\ \ge \int\limits_{|y-a|\le \delta/2} f(y)\,\int\limits_{|x+y|\le \delta} g(x)\,dx\ dy$$
Observe that if $|y-a|\le \delta/2$ and $|x+a|\le \delta/2$ then $|x+y|\le \delta.$ Hence
$$\int\limits_{|y-a|\le \delta/2} f(y)\,\int\limits_{|x+y|\le \delta} g(x)\,dx\ dy \\ \ge \int\limits_{|y-a|\le \delta/2} f(y)\,\int\limits_{|x+a|\le \delta/2} g(x)\,dx\ dy\\
=\int\limits_{|y-a|\le \delta/2} f(y)\,dy \  \int\limits_{|x-(-a)|\le \delta/2} g(x)\,dx>0 $$